# Go to source code line in Chrome dev tools extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to make a [dev tools Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) that lets the user go to specific points in the page's source code (whenever the page's source code calls some global function `foo` that I inject into the page via an extension content script).

I can get a stack trace by having function `foo` throw an exception and then catch it.

But how can I tell Chrome dev tools to go navigate to a certain line in the source code? Is there an API call for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an API function just for that, [`chrome.devtools.panels.openResource`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_panels#method-openResource).
Note that line numbers are zero-based for this API.

```
// Opens line 34 of file https://example.com/test.js, assuming this resource is present:
chrome.devtools.panels.openResource("https://example.com/test.js", 33, function() {
  // Resource should be open, but no way to test that it succeeded
});
```

Comment: How is possible to navigate to a column also? (line + column) Thanks